# How to check equality in multiple lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have created a clause for checking if 2 calls to a function func return the same output, returning true if the outputs are the same, returning false if the outputs are not equal.

```
same([Current|Rest], Max, Solution) :-
   NewMax is Max-1,
   Ans1 = func([Current|Rest], Max, Solution1),
   Ans2 =func([Current|Rest], NewMax, Solution),
   Ans1 = Ans2.  

Example outputs of func:
`
?- func([a], 2, X).
X = [a, b, d] ;
X = [a, f, i] ;
false.

?- func([a], 3, X).
X = [a, b, d] ;
X = [a, f, i] ;
false.

?- func([a], 4, X).
X = [a, b, d] ;
X = [a, f, i] ;
X = [a, f, i, j, m] ;
false.
```

Therefor, the desired output from the same/3 would be:

```
?- same([a], 4, X).
false

?- same([a], 3, X).
true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understood your problem, you may want to check out [`findall/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) and [`between/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)

Comment: Also, why did you tag the question with `tree` and `artificial-intelligence` ?

Comment: I did attempt findall, I wasn't sure how to limit it to just 2 entries. To try to clear it up, I'm checking whether the output of func([List], Number, Solution), is the same or not when Number= Number and when Number= Number -1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> `Ans1 = func([Current|Rest], Max, Solution1),`

Prolog has no function calls. What this line means is "unify the variable `Ans1` with the term `func([Current|Rest], Max, Solution1)`". It does *not* mean something like "call `func` and return its result", because Prolog has no function calls.

If you write this line as:

```
func([Current|Rest], Max, Solution1),
```

then the predicate `func` will be called and unify the variable `Solution1` with some term. This is the analogue of "returning a value" in Prolog.

So if you want to call `func` twice and compare the "return values" for equality, you could do this:

```
func([Current|Rest], Max, Solution1),
func([Current|Rest], NewMax, Solution2),
Solution1 = Solution2
```

If you only want this to succeed if `Solution1 = Solution2`, *and additionally* you want to bind the variable `Solution` to this same value, you could add a line:

```
Solution = Solution1
```

at the end. But also you could write the whole thing like this:

```
same([Current|Rest], Max, Solution) :-
   NewMax is Max-1,
   func([Current|Rest], Max, Solution),
   func([Current|Rest], NewMax, Solution).
```

This will fail if the two calls to `func` try to bind `Solution` to different terms. It will succeed if they try to bind `Solution` to unifiable terms.